# Rshiny: Why is my slider displaying the slider value in a separate box?

Tags: r, shiny, widget, slider, shinyapps

I am having a small issue with my shiny app that seems to have appeared out of nowhere. My slider is now showing the value in a separate box below the slider, but I have not changed any code related to the slider. I am a little confused as my *other sliders* in my app are constructed in the same manner, but the issue is *only effecting this slider*.

I have attached a picture below. Unfortunately, I cannot display all of my code, but the slider code was standard (I define the value variable earlier in the code)The slider is part of a conditional panel. It is worth noting that when I change the selection to the other condition, I do not have this issue with my other slider:

`

```
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.pl == 'A'",
       sliderInput("a", "Price", value = a_start, min = 0, max = 170),
       actionButton("revert_a", "Revert")
                     ),
     conditionalPanel(
       condition = "input.pl == 'B'",
       sliderInput("b", "Price", value = b_start, min = 0, max = 185),
       actionButton("revert_b", "Revert")
                     ),
```

`

I have been searching for an answer, but have yet to see this anywhere. Any help or advice on what to look for (in the server perhaps) would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image: Info]

Comment: Can you at post the code immediately after and before the sliderInput? Did you change/update any package versions recently? What version of shiny is this (attaching the output of `sessionInfo()` should be enough)?
I believe that I might have seen this before, but I need more details to help you.

Comment: I will try to make some modifications to my code so I can post it here....In the meantime,  I actually did update some packages today ! I have added the output of sessionInfo() to my question.

Comment: Post has also been edited to show some of the code surrounding the slider

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but what do you mean when you say that you "change the selection to the other condition"? You mean that changing the `condition = "input.p == 'A'"` makes it work as intended?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear. I mean when `condition = "input.p == 'A'"` the box does appear, but when it is not equal to A the box does not appear. I can edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Wait, but if the condition is false the slider also shouldn't appear, isn't that right? Do you have that box somewhere below the slider? I can't reproduce anything like this on my local version, so it might be worth it for you to try to reproduce it in a smaller example (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3312701).

Comment: Another slider appears with the new condition. I will update my post to reflect that and try to think of a way to post a sample of my code !

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you opening the app in the RStudio browser ?